# How to flush out jobs on a Mesos slave?

Tags: scheduler, distributed-computing, mesos, mesosphere

I want to take out a host (mesos-slave) from the mesos cluster in a clean manner by draining out the executors its running. Is it possible for mesos-master to not give any further work to a mesos-slave but still receive updates for the currently running executors? If thats possible, I can make mesos-master not give anymore work to this slave and once the slave is done with its currently running executors, I can take it out. Please feel free to suggest a better way of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you look for maintenance primitives, which have been recently added to Mesos. A user doc is [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/maintenance/).